# Como posso adquirir imagem do imagemView dentro de um LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android

Como o titulo informa estou tentando obter uma das imagens dos imageView que fica dentro de um LinearLayout, Eu tentei utilizar o comando linearLayout.getChildAt(3) para obter uma das 9 imagem e adicionar a uma outra ImageView maior separada do LinearLayout, porem não estou obtendo essa imagem, pelo que estou vendo está pegando apenas o filho, sem a imagem inclusa nele, como posso obter essa imagem ?

OBS: Ao utilizar o comando Log.e("Childs", linearLayout.getChildCount()) é informado que existe 9 filhos no linearlayout, que se refere aos 9 imageView;

Answer (score 1):

Como sei que estou querendo pegar o elemento de uma ImageView essa é a solução:

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) linearLayout.getChildAt(3);
//É importante o cast ImageView.
```

através dessa variavel "imgView" eu consigo pegar o drawable e adiciona a uma outra ImageView.

```
ImageView imageView2 = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                              
imageView2.setImageDrawable(imageView.getDrawable());
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).